# Rails: Change Form Method on Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app and I have a form where I want to change the method (:put vs :post) based upon the condition: `params[id].to_s.present?`. Here is my attempt, but no matter what I do, I get various errors:

```
<%= form_tag( country_pend_create_path(), "#{params[:id].to_s.present? ? ':method => :put' : ':method => :post'}", :class => 'form-horizontal') do %>
```

Know I know that `form_for()` preforms this purpose automatically, but I cannot and do not want to use `form_for()` for this form. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write as:

```
<%= form_tag( country_pend_create_path(), :method => params[:id].present? ? :put : :post, :class => 'form-horizontal') do %>
```

Comment: for simple case like that, yes it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [lambda](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda):

```
<%= form_tag( country_pend_create_path(), :method => lambda { params[:id].present? ? :put : :post }, :class => 'form-horizontal') do %>
```

(I removed the `to_s` since I don't think it changes anything, add it back if it's important.)